# Building web applications with tools that last

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I recently began as a web designer but spend more and more time learning front end web development. I enjoy Javascript and the work. I am very interested in creating web applications unfortunately I find that Javascript frameworks change so quickly. I began learning Angular 1.3 only to find the release of 2.0 to kill my interest. I also worry that learning frameworks will not help my skill as a developer only as a framework user. It makes me want to just develop with modular Vanilla.

What recommendations do you have for creating web applications with this problem in mind? I greatly appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best things you can learn as a developer is to ALWAYS find a solution before creating one.

Yes, vanilla Javascript surely has it's place, for as you progress as a developer, you too will want to write your own javascript.

I recently just got into MEAN stack development, and I can definitely say if I were to try to write all of this by hand, especially if your not an expert, would be a nightmare, if not impossible/impractical.

I understand the craving / desire, we all have it. We start to code and feel like wizards when we can conjure up this neat program we build all by ourselves. But we also have to realize there is a little bit of reasoning behind utilizing frameworks, just take this into perspective, taking MEAN stack as an example,

Right now, there are a team of developers working on MongoDB, a team of developers working on Angular, Express, NodeJS etc.

Each of these frameworks is being FOCUSED on and perfected, think about that for a second. These aren't things that are just thrown together, these are strong written frameworks, and when combined together, can make an awesome toolset.

Building your own library can also be a good idea, and I would encourage it, especially for CUSTOM solutions. This can be fun and creative.

However, as for making the strongest web framework you can have, it would take more work than whats practical. Utilizing the work of others is one of the most important things you can do as a developer! Good luck.

Comment: "One of the best things you can learn as a developer is to ALWAYS find a solution before creating one." I would only agree with this if you already have a good understanding of how to create the solution. I know developers who can't script their way out of a paper bag because they just use plugins and other peoples code for everything.

Comment: If you can't code your way out of a paper bag, then your not ready to learn a framework. Someone being a beginner in a framework should be well versed in their desired language.

Answer (score 0):

You could resort to [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/) to figure out which technologies last and where the trend is going. A quick research points very much to the study of jQuery (even though AngularJS trend is more impressive):

http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=AngularJS%2C%20%2Fm%2F0268gyp%2C%20%2Fm%2F02p97&cmpt=q&tz=

Going Vanilla is always a good idea in order to strengthen your understanding of the fundamentals - learning some popular frameworks is essential to work productively and find good projects!

Comment: I have never used google trends before so this was very eye opening to me. Javascript interest has declined...surprising to me. Looks like angular is almost a no trend compared to the others.

Comment: The graph is a bit misleading - AngularJS is by far the most popular javascript framework after jQuery especially considering that it is not around for that long. If you check for EmberJs or BackboneJs, they hardly show any trend-uptick at all.

Comment: Ah your right, I suppose I should have compared it to similar frameworks. 

I learned Jquery first then Javascript...maybe I should learn Angular first and then build a small framework myself? Sinking all this time into a framework and having it gone in a few years sure rubs me the wrong way but I guess that's the nature of the work.